Constructing MultiPolygon for country using Overpass
I have the following overpass query, giving a country's coastlines:
[out:json][timeout:2500];
rel(13428950);map_to_area->.region;
(
    way["natural"="coastline"](area.region);
);
(._;>;);out geom;

I wish to construct the MultiPolygon that these coastlines represent. However, the coastlines are returned as a mix of Point, Polygon and LineString objects. Why is this?
To create the MultiPolygon, should I be performing a different query, or should I be processing the response in Python instead? If the former, what query should I use? If the latter, what strategy should I use to create the Multipolygon?
I will eventually simplify the MultiPolygon and reduce the number of islands, to my own taste.

Data returned by the Overpass API strictly follows the OpenStreetMap data model, i.e. it comes as relations, ways and nodes (rather than Point, Polygon and LineString). Also note that Overpass API cannot do any sort of post processing you would need here.
Since coastline processing is a bit involved, you might want to take a look at existing offerings first, such as https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/land-polygons.html ... this page also lists some of the relevant tools, and provides some further background on the topic.

Thanks I'll try that!
